# How to read pixel data only not meta data from 16 bit image in c#?

Tags: c#, image, byte

I have 16 bit depth image from that I want to read only pixel data and store it to byte[]

I tried following code :

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Image stitch API\\Temp\\output.tif");
byte[] data = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
```

I also tried the following :

```
Image img;
img = Image.FromFile("C:\\Image stitch API\\Temp\\output.tif");
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
byte[] data = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]))
```

Here all data it is coming from image, but I need only pixel data?

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can load your image as Bitmap, it is pretty easy to get pixel info as shown below.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("somefile.ext");
    Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)
```

GetPixel() will return Color (struct) type and you can get individual channel values as byte like shown below.

```
    byte g = slateBlue.G;
    byte b = slateBlue.B;
    byte r = slateBlue.R;
    byte a = slateBlue.A;
```

Regarding your comment, I will suggest you to use use [Netvips](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips)  to manipulate image in byte array form (it is way betterand faster than system.drawing). By doing so, you could get image bands as byte arrays as below.

```
    var imageBands = inputImage.Bandsplit();
    var R = imageBands [0];
    var B = imageBands [1];
    var G = imageBands [2];
```

If you dont wanna switch the libraries, you could get byte array with System.Drawing like shown below.

```
byte[] image = new[] {R, B, G};
```

Comment: here i need byte array, here how can we specify byte[] size and adding values into byte array

Comment: What is the outcome?

Comment: i used following way ,                                                                               Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("somefile.ext");                                           byte[] data = nbyte[imgLength];
int pixelPosition = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
 {
Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);
data[pixelPosition] = pixel.R;
data[pixelPosition + 1] = pixel.G;
data[pixelPosition + 2] = pixel.B;
data[pixelPosition + 3] = pixel.A;
pixelPosition = pixelPosition + 4;
}
}

Comment: Nice, hope that solved your problem! If so, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get image data out of an image is to use `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy`.

I **strongly** advice against using `GetPixel`. See, `LockBits` works by reserving memory for putting the bytes of the image and copying the bytes of the image in there. `UnlockBits` will then clean up that reserved memory.

Now, the problem is, `GetPixel` performs this same locking and unlocking operation for *every single pixel you access*. Using LockBits once is fairly fast, but using it over and over for tens of thousands of pixels *really* slows things down.

Note that there are two ways of using `LockBits`; either you get the data in the original pixel format, using `sourceImage.PixelFormat`, or you make LockBits *convert* the data to the format you require, by giving a different one. In this code, I force the output to the pixel format `Format32bppArgb`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the raw bytes from an image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceImage">The image to get the bytes from.</param>
/// <returns>The raw bytes of the image</returns>
public static Byte[] GetImageDataAs32bppArgb(Bitmap sourceImage)
{
    BitmapData sourceData = sourceImage.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Byte[] data = new Byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceImage.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
    sourceImage.UnlockBits(sourceData);
    return data;
}
```

`Stride` can normally differ from `width * bpp` since lines of bitmaps are always aligned to multiples of 4 bytes, so normally you need to return that as well and keep track of it, but since this is a 32-bit format, its data is *always* aligned to 4 bytes, so there is never an actual difference here.

Note, your question never specifies the *order* in which you need the data. Typical ARGB data is actually in the byte order B, G, R, A, because normal integer saving on IBM PC architecture is little-endian, meaning that the actual bytes of an Int32 value "FFEEDDCC" are reversed in memory to [CC DD EE FF]. But your comment on the other answer given here seemed to indicate you went for byte order [RR, GG, BB, AA], or, 'ABGR', which is honestly not a format I've *ever* seen before. But if you do need to change that, it's just a simple extra loop to exchange red and blue:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 4)
{
    Byte b = data[i]; // save Blue
    data[i] = data[i + 2]; // set first component to the Red value
    data[i + 2] = b; // set third component to the Blue value
}
```