# Optimizing Image Processing Code for Performance

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, bitmap

I have an image processing code that works but is very slow. I've tried to optimize it using lockbits and parallel processing, but the optimized code is not producing the expected results. I'm hoping someone can help me identify and resolve the performance issues.

Here's the original code that works but is slow:

```
        private void Form1_Load()
        {
            last_action = "Form1_Load";
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;
            int div = 8;
            int scopeLen = width / div;
            int[][] bwColorScope = new int[256][];
            int[][] bColorScope = new int[256][];
            int[][] gColorScope = new int[256][];
            int[][] rColorScope = new int[256][];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                bwColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
                bColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
                gColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
                rColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < scopeLen; l++)
            {
                for (int x = l * div; x < (l + 1) * div; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                        int grayValue = (int)(pixel.R * 0.3 + pixel.G * 0.59 + pixel.B * 0.11);
                        bwColorScope[255 - grayValue][l] += 1;
                        bColorScope[255 - pixel.B][l] += 1;
                        gColorScope[255 - pixel.G][l] += 1;
                        rColorScope[255 - pixel.R][l] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            width = bwColorScope[0].Length;
            height = bwColorScope.Length;
            Bitmap scopeImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int value = Math.Min(bwColorScope[y][x], 255);
                    if (value < 50)
                    {
                        scopeImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
                    scopeImage.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            Bitmap scopeImage1 = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int value = Math.Min(bColorScope[y][x], 255);
                    if (value < 50)
                    {
                        scopeImage1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(value, value, 255);
                    scopeImage1.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            Bitmap scopeImage2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int value = Math.Min(gColorScope[y][x], 255);
                    if (value < 50)
                    {
                        scopeImage2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(value, 255, value);
                    scopeImage2.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            Bitmap scopeImage3 = new Bitmap(width, height);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int value = Math.Min(rColorScope[y][x], 255);
                    if (value < 50)
                    {
                        scopeImage3.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                        continue;
                    }
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, value, value);
                    scopeImage3.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(scopeImage.Width, scopeImage.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(scopeImage, 0, 0);
                ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
                ColorMatrix colorMatrix2 = new ColorMatrix();
                colorMatrix2.Matrix33 = .3f;
                imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix2, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
                g.DrawImage(scopeImage1, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
                g.DrawImage(scopeImage2, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
                g.DrawImage(scopeImage3, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
            }
            pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
        }
```

And here's the optimized code I tried, but it's not working as expected:

```
private void Form1_Load()
{
    last_action = "Form1_Load";
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); // Create a new bitmap to ensure it's not locked.
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;
    int div = 8;
    int scopeLen = width / div;

    // Create arrays to store color data
    int[][] bwColorScope = new int[256][];
    int[][] bColorScope = new int[256][];
    int[][] gColorScope = new int[256][];
    int[][] rColorScope = new int[256][];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        bwColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
        bColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
        gColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
        rColorScope[i] = new int[scopeLen + 1];
    }

    // Lock the image bits for faster access
    BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;

        for (int l = 0; l < scopeLen; l++)
        {
            Parallel.For(l * div, (l + 1) * div, x =>
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    byte* pixel = ptr + (x + y * width) * 4;
                    int grayValue = (int)(pixel[2] * 0.3 + pixel[1] * 0.59 + pixel[0] * 0.11);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref bwColorScope[255 - grayValue][l]);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref bColorScope[255 - pixel[0]][l]);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref gColorScope[255 - pixel[1]][l]);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref rColorScope[255 - pixel[2]][l]);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    image.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    // Create and update scope images
    Bitmap[] scopeImages = new Bitmap[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        scopeImages[i] = new Bitmap(width, height);

        Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int value = 255;
                if (i == 0)
                    value = Math.Min(bwColorScope[y][x], 255);
                else if (i == 1)
                    value = Math.Min(bColorScope[y][x], 255);
                else if (i == 2)
                    value = Math.Min(gColorScope[y][x], 255);
                else if (i == 3)
                    value = Math.Min(rColorScope[y][x], 255);

                if (value < 50)
                {
                    scopeImages[i].SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Color color = i == 1 ? Color.FromArgb(value, value, 255) :
                                    i == 2 ? Color.FromArgb(value, 255, value) :
                                    i == 3 ? Color.FromArgb(255, value, value) :
                                    Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);

                    scopeImages[i].SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Combine the scope images
    Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(scopeImages[0].Width, scopeImages[0].Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resultBitmap))
    {
        g.DrawImage(scopeImages[0], 0, 0);
        ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix2 = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix2.Matrix33 = .3f;
        imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix2, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            g.DrawImage(scopeImages[i], new Rectangle(0, 0, resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height), 0, 0, resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
        }
    }

    pictureBox2.Image = resultBitmap;
}
```

The main problem I'm facing is the slow execution time with the original code, and the optimized code is not producing the correct output. I'm looking for guidance on how to speed up the original code or help with fixing the issues in the optimized code. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Edit:

this is the expected image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWyZY.png)

and this is the second code output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwIB8.png)

Edit 2:
this is my new code that works perfect but it's a little slow (400 milisecond) but i want speed even more.

```
        private void Form1_Load()
        {
            last_action = "Form1_Load";
            Bitmap cimg = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            int div = 1;
            int scopeLen = cimg.Width / div;
            int[,] bwColorScope = new int[scopeLen + 1, 256];
            int[,] bColorScope = new int[256, scopeLen + 1];
            int[,] gColorScope = new int[256, scopeLen + 1];
            int[,] rColorScope = new int[256, scopeLen + 1];
            for (int l = 0; l < scopeLen; l++)
            {
                for (int x = l * div; x < (l + 1) * div; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixelColor = cimg.GetPixel(x, y);
                        bColorScope[255 - pixelColor.B, l]++;
                        gColorScope[255 - pixelColor.G, l]++;
                        rColorScope[255 - pixelColor.R, l]++;
                        bwColorScope[l, 255 - pixelColor.R]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int width = bColorScope.GetLength(1);
            int height = bColorScope.GetLength(0);
            Bitmap bwColorScopeImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Bitmap bchannelImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Bitmap rchannelImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Bitmap gchannelImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            if (!dim)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        bwColorScopeImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, bwColorScope[x, y]), 255, 255, 255));
                        bchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, bColorScope[y, x]), 0, 0, 255));
                        rchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, rColorScope[y, x]), 255, 0, 0));
                        gchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, gColorScope[y, x]), 0, 255, 0));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        int colorValue = 255 - y;
                        bwColorScopeImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, bwColorScope[x, y]), colorValue, colorValue, colorValue));
                        bchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, bColorScope[y, x]), colorValue, colorValue, 255));
                        rchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, rColorScope[y, x]), 255, colorValue, colorValue));
                        gchannelImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Math.Min(255, gColorScope[y, x]), colorValue, 255, colorValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(bwColorScopeImage.Width, bwColorScopeImage.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox2.Image))
            {
                g.DrawImage(bwColorScopeImage, Point.Empty);
                g.DrawImage(bchannelImage, Point.Empty);
                g.DrawImage(rchannelImage, Point.Empty);
                g.DrawImage(gchannelImage, Point.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your rather complex code is completely undocumented. How should we know what it's doing? Also, if you've got a conceptual problem with your algorithm (here: It's slow because it has time complexity O(n^3)), just adding parallel processing won't really help much.

Comment: You really should be clearer as to how exactly the results are unexpected! Add an image!! - I don't have to time really dig into it but at 1st glance I miss the part where the scanlines get padded to multiples of 4, which is needed for lockbit access to a bitmap. Look up `BitmapData.Stride` ! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411114/c-sharp-copy-bitmaps-pixels-in-the-alpha-channel-on-another-bitmap/24411925#24411925) - Also: I guess you realize that the pixels usually contain ABGR values..

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to apply a filter. In this case, check how a ColorMatrix works, e.g., [How can I gray-out a disabled PictureBox used as Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584671/7444103) and similar, using `Bitmap.LockBits()` (in a more *sensible* way): [Analyze colors of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59102380/7444103); applying a sepia filter, doesn't change much

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) library (disclaimer: written by me) for much faster Get/SetPixel and parallelized image processing features. For a GDI+ `Bitmap` you can use the [`TransformColors`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_TransformColors_1.htm) extension method to apply a custom filter to an image in-place. To return a new instance instead, you can use the [`ConvertPixelFormat`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat.htm) method with a custom predefined quantizer.

Comment: @TaW Just added images.

Comment: @TaW I saw your answer and i didn't get it. My question is how can i speed up setpixel with that method... . Can you write me an answer?

Comment: @TaW I also added my new code.

Comment: @user22731523 Look into `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy`. [Here's an example of how to use these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908231/395685).